# Error because "static" at C++ code

Tags: c++, oop, static

I'm introducing at c++'s oop and I have a question.
When I declare a function as static at the headers file, why i get an error if I put static too at the code file? I mean, why static should go only at the header's file?

The menssage error:

mod.cc:71:40: error: cannot declare member function ‘static int mod::mida_maxima()’ to have static linkage [-fpermissive]

Comment: Please post an example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Headers: static bool function();
Code: static bool function() {//code// }

If i declare the function as static at the code file I get an error, my question is why.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. And yes, please do include the complete error message for the MCVE.

Comment: @koopad: In your question, please [and it would be great if it's a COMPLETE example, not just two lines of code without context]

Comment: I'd say it's a completely arbitrary rule, but perhaps there are some Stroustrup insights on this to be found in "The Design and Evolution of C++".

Comment: The error clearly indicates you left out very relevant information that's still only hinted at now: the fact that the "function" you're asking about is a member function. How should anyone have guessed that based on your original question? Especially if you comment to give an example with a non-member function? Take a look at your own question. If I asked this question, would you be able to reproduce the problem? If not, you should edit it until it contains enough information that you would be able to.

Answer (score 1):

A `static` member function inside a `class` is a class function; it works without any receiver, so `this` cannot be used inside it. However, it is visible in any compilation unit have its declaration.

When you define a `static` function it has `static` linkage so is only visible from its compilation unit (a bit like the `static` keyword of C). Obviously a class function should often be visible from the whole program (not just a single compilation unit).

Hence, the *definition* of  a `static` member function should *not* be `static`, in other words:

```
 // perhaps in a header file
 class Foo {
   static void memberfun (int); // class member function declaration
 };

 // definition in the compilation unit
 void // static is forbidden here 
 Foo::memberfun(int arg) {
   /// some body
 }
```

In other words, C++ reused the `static` keyword for two unrelated purposes: definition of *class* members and declaration of static linkage (inspired by C).

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: I think this answer does not really address the question why `static` is forbidden at the definition of the function. As far as I see it, the language could as well allow `static` there, because at this point it is known from the declaration that `memberfun` is `static`, so it wouldn't make any difference. I suspect historical reasons behind this, but I don't know.

Comment: No, `static` has also a visibility role inspired by C. In addition, it is used to define class members (not instance members)